# Android Event Propagation in Multi Layer Activity

Tags: android, button, swipe

I tried to add swipe event for the screen which has got bunch of buttons. the swipe is not working for buttons. In other words, if i swipe on top of buttons, swipe event is not recognized. So, I tried 2 (top and bottom) layers of layout in Activity. Top for handling swipe and bottom for buttons and other UI elements. But, the top layer is taking all the event and Bottom is not accessible. Is there any ways to that i can send the click event to bottom layer.

The main requirement is, handling swipe and click in a screen with bunch of button. Swipe is not recognized by buttons.

How to solve this problem.

Comment: have you find the solution for that? I am now using ViewPager as the top layer and two button as the bottom layer. The button cannot get any click event. Event when I return false in onTouchEvent

Answer (score 0):

Your `onTouchEvent()` for the top layer must return `false` if it wants anything underneath to see the touch event.  It should return `true` only if it has handled the event and it does not need to be propagated any further.